# Is there maximum number of characters permissible in rownames or colnames in R?

Tags: r

My script generates row and column names with increasingly large number of characters.

Is there a maximum number of characters in a row or column name permissible for a R matrix?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Row and column names are attributes of a data frame or matrix object.  As such, they are only limited by the system resources available to R.

```
x <- data.frame(col = 0)
object.size(x)
# 680 bytes

# Huge name for a column
colnames(x)=paste(rep("x",10^8),collapse="")
object.size(x)
# 100000680 bytes
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice simple idea to test premise.

Comment: @RayCzaplewski If this answered your question, please click the checkmark next to the answer--that helps us know which questions have been answered, gives the answerer 15 rep, and gives you 2 rep as a reward for doing the right thing.  Thanks!